# Relative path not working in .htaccess rewriterule - need to redirect without changing the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, relative-path

It looks like there are many questions on here regarding RewriteRules, relative paths, and redirecting without changing the URL - however, in all of my searching, none of them seem to answer my specific scenario.

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !^images
 RewriteRule ^files(.*)$ ../../fileManager/server/php/files$1 [L]
```

Basically what this is doing is, if the URL someone enters contains the word "files" after the root directory, it then redirects them to a path which is up two directories, which actually contains the file.

For example, if you go to "http://www.example.com/files/username/myImage.jpg", it will actually redirect you to "http://s281192971.onlinehome.us/cms/fileManager/server/php/files/username/myImage.jpg".

The problem with this is that it works great locally, but when I upload it to my server, it stops working.

One way I found around this was to just specify the absolute path to the file path like so:

```
 RewriteRule ^files(.*)$ http://s281192971.onlinehome.us/cms/fileManager/server/php/files$1 [L]
```

And that "works" - but the problem is, it changes the URL as well. I would prefer to keep the URL that the user typed in (http://www.example.com/files/username/myImage.jpg", rather than the absolute path.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this but the docs state you can use the URL-path for substitution.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

My guess would be making your rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^cms/mysite/files(.*)$ /fileManager/server/php/files$1 [L]
```

Comment: Alas - no dice. The page that I am redirecting to is two directories above where I have the .htaccess file - and so without having some sort of "../" in there, I don't know how it would know to look in directories higher up.

Comment: Is it possible to create symlinks on the server? That way you could provide a door to the other directory.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am "able" - but I don't know how. Do you have a script or something I could try to see if it works?

Comment: No need for symlinks. I tested the URL-path approach and it's works. Based on the example in your question I altered the rule.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I apologize for overlooking this, but my links are wrong in my initial example. The user will never actually be entering in "http://www.mydomain.com/cms/mysite/files/myFile.png". They will actually just be going to "http://www.mydomain.com/files/username/myFile.png". If they go to THAT url, that "path" technically doesn't exist. "myFile.png" actually sits up two directories, in the /fileManager/server/php/files path.  So by having the RewriteRule include ^cms/mysite/files(.*)$, it would actually never get fired, because they would never try to access that URL, if that makes sense

Comment: You mean the directory is outside out the webroot? If this is the case then symlinks are the only option I know of. Creating a link in the webroot `ln -s ../../fileManager ./files` and remove the rewrite rule.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid - but when you say to "create a link in the webroot" - how do I do that? Would I create another .htaccess file in the root with the code you specified?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26162/discussion-between-bart-and-john-hubler)